# When I tapped segment Odd or even I am getting true and false value in Tableview instead of odd value or even value

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segment

When I press odd it shows true or false. How can Get values of array I'm trying to print odd value when i tap odd on segment or even values when i tap even , How can get this. I'm new in ios. Please help

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var segmentOutlet: UISegmentedControl!
    let numberArray = Array(1...100)
    var segmentIndex  = 0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }
    @IBAction func segmentControl(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        

        tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return numberArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell : TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.numberLbl.text = String(numberArray[indexPath.row])
        if segmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            cell.numberLbl.text = String(numberArray[indexPath.row] % 2 == 0)
            
        }
        if segmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex == 2 {
            cell.numberLbl.text = String(numberArray[indexPath.row] % 2 == 1)
        }
        
        return cell
    }
}
```

my Simulator image:

[image: code file]

Comment: `numberArray[indexPath.row] % 2 == 0` evaluates to either `true` or `false`. Where will you get the odd/even number?

Comment: How can I get values ?

Comment: Oh, are you trying to show a list of `1 3 5 7 9....` for odd, and `2 4 6 8....` for even?

Comment: Yes sir, 1 3 5 7 9.... for odd, and 2 4 6 8.... for even.

Comment: You should make it two AND conditions instead like `if segmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 && numberArray[indexPath.row].isMultiple(of: 2) {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `numberArray[indexPath.row] % 2 == 0` has a `==`, which evaluates to true/false. It doesn't really make sense. Also, there's no need to check if the current `indexPath.row` is odd or even... you're trying to display a list of even or odd numbers, so what does `indexPath.row` have to do with that?

Instead, try making a second array, `filteredArray`. This will be where the table view directly gets its data from.

```
let numberArray = Array(1...100)
lazy var filteredArray: [Int] = { numberArray }() /// return `numberArray` by default
```

You can then update `filteredArray` based on the `selectedSegmentIndex`.

```
@IBAction func segmentControl(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 1: /// even numbers
        filteredArray = numberArray.filter { $0 % 2 == 0}
    case 2: /// odd numbers
        filteredArray = numberArray.filter { $0 % 2 == 1}
    default: /// all numbers
        filteredArray = numberArray
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Finally, just read from `filteredArray` in your data source methods.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredArray.count /// use `filteredArray`
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! TableViewCell
    cell.numberLbl.text = String(filteredArray[indexPath.row]) /// also use `filteredArray`
    return cell
}
```

Comment: @Fatehprajapat if the answer worked, can you click the green checkmark to accept it?

Comment: If you are going to introduce a new property then why not make it two, one array for even and one for odd numbers? I mean it’s not like 4 will sometimes be odd and sometimes even… Otherwise see my comment above for a more dynamic solution

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that's what I originally thought of in my deleted answer, but OP has a "Numbers" tab that I assume should show all the numbers, even or odd. And also if there's separate arrays, you'd need to check `segmentOutlet.selectedSegmentIndex` inside *both* `numberOfRowsInSection ` and `cellForRowAt`, right?